# ¿Cómo cambiar el color de la barra de notificaciones en Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Estoy realizando una app en Android Studio, y quiero que cambie el color de la barra de notificaciones, el problema es que todos los tutoriales que he encontrado hasta ahora son para apps donde aún tiene la barra de titulo que crea por defecto android studio, y es aquí donde surge mi problema, ya que he quitado esta para mi app y no estoy usando ninguna. Necesito saber si hay una manera para cambiarla sin tener que poner la barra de titulo.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si no estas utilizando la barra por defecto de android entonces tendras que agregar el codigo de la que estas utilizando si quieres ayuda.

Comment: No estoy utilizando ninguna barra. ese es el problema